# Deserialize gson Object with nested List<Object>

Tags: serialization, gson

```
public class ListResult<T> {

    private boolean ok;
    private String message;
    private java.util.List<T> data;
    private Paging paging;
}
```

When i want to deserialize JSON given form RESTful call like this :

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<ListResult<T>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object model = gson.fromJson(strResult, fooType);
```

A get A ListResult where data field is a list of StringMap instead a List of T like defined in ListResult class

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Type fooType = new TypeToken<ListResult<StringMap>>() {}.getType();
Gson gson = new Gson();
ListResult<StringMap> model = gson.fromJson(strResult, fooType);
```

`Gson` can't read your mind, or determine a Generic type all on its own ;)

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types

Answer (score -1):

Just don't use a list, use an array  `MyObj[] myObjs`. You don't need to use the TypeToken way