# gson deserialize object hierarchy

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I have the following Classes:

Class: TestClass:

```
public class TestXClass {

    Map<String, NestedClass> embeddedMap1;
    Map<String, List<NestedClass>> embeddedMap2;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestClass [embeddedMap1=" + embeddedMap1 + "(" + embeddedMap1.getClass() + "), embeddedMap2=" + embeddedMap2 + "(" + embeddedMap2.getClass()+ ")]";
    }
}
```

Class: NestedClass:

```
public class NestedClass {

    Map<String, Integer> embeddedMap;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NestedClass [embeddedMap=" + embeddedMap + "("+ 
    embeddedMap.getClass() +")]";
    }
}
```

I want to serialize and deserialize an object of TestClass to and from JSON with gson.

This is my testcode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    TestClass test = new TestClass();
    test.embeddedMap1 = new HashMap<>();

    NestedClass testNested1 = new NestedClass();
    testNested1.embeddedMap = new HashMap<>();
    testNested1.embeddedMap.put("X", 1);
    test.embeddedMap1.put("A", testNested1);

    List<NestedClass> testNestedList = new ArrayList<>();
    NestedClass listElement = new NestedClass();
    listElement.embeddedMap = new HashMap<>();
    listElement.embeddedMap.put("ABC", 3);
    testNestedList.add(listElement);

    test.embeddedMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    test.embeddedMap2.put("Z", testNestedList);

    String jsonString = gson.toJson(test);

    System.out.println(jsonString);

    TestClass fromJson = gson.fromJson(jsonString, TestClass.class);
    System.out.println(fromJson);
}
```

The serialization to Json works fine:

```
{
  "embeddedMap1": {
    "A": {
      "embeddedMap": {
        "X": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "embeddedMap2": {
    "Z": [
      {
        "embeddedMap": {
          "ABC": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I try to deserialize it to my TestClass, I have the following output:

> TestClass [embeddedMap1= {A=NestedClass [embeddedMap={X=1}(class
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap)]}(class
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap), embeddedMap2={Z=[NestedClass
>   [embeddedMap={ABC=3}(class
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap)]]}(class
>   com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap)]

Every Map or List is Replaced by a type of gson.

How can I deserialize such an object structure to plain java types?

Comment: You need to use a TypeToken for JSON to determine generics. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950415/deserialize-gson-object-with-nested-listobject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize gson Object with nested List<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950415/deserialize-gson-object-with-nested-listobject)

Comment: What's wrong with the Map implementation that Gson uses?

Comment: @Strelok Because the testclass is my objectmodel and this will be transported through several components. So it can happens, that it will result in a classNotFoundException if the gson.jar is not present in a other component. It will be not a good style to provide the gson.jar everywhere only to prevent the exeption.

Comment: @Jotunacorn: Since gson 2.8. there is no constructor for TypeToken. And the examples are not helpfull for my object structure. Can you explain hat the TypeToken has to be created for my object?

Comment: In one of my current projects i deserialise with
mGson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<ArrayList<UserRefYto>>() {}.getType())
This is hopefully applicable in your case too. Otherwise you have to implement your own JsonDeserialiser<Map> to tell Gson how to deserialise the maps.